# TQSL - Combine 3 temp tables (each contain date spans) to every possible combination with out causing overlaps

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to combine three temp tables each with a Begin and End Span for different metrics to create one combined table with all possible spans.  The script below creates all three temp tables and (Attached Excel) shows what the results should end up being but I am not able to get to that as yet.  :)

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#aoRepGroupMbrHistory', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #aoRepGroupMbrHistory
CREATE TABLE #aoRepGroupMbrHistory
(
     syUserID INT
     , aoRepGroupID INT
     , Hist_EffectStart DATETIME
     , Hist_EffectiveEnd DATETIME
     , RepGroupName VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO #aoRepGroupMbrHistory VALUES (17716, 165, '2010-06-03 00:00:00.000', '2012-03-01 23:59:59.997', 'UG - All Skills Reps')
INSERT INTO #aoRepGroupMbrHistory VALUES (17716, 772, '2012-03-02 00:00:00.000', '2012-06-26 23:59:59.997', 'UG - Tier 1 LC Reps')
INSERT INTO #aoRepGroupMbrHistory VALUES (17716, 797, '2012-06-27 00:00:00.000', '2012-11-08 23:59:59.997', 'UG - Aggregators Reps')
INSERT INTO #aoRepGroupMbrHistory VALUES (17716, 165, '2012-11-09 00:00:00.000', '2012-11-29 23:59:59.997', 'UG - All Skills Reps')
INSERT INTO #aoRepGroupMbrHistory VALUES (17716, 797, '2012-11-30 00:00:00.000', '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000', 'UG - Aggregators Reps')

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#TeamMemberHistory', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TeamMemberHistory
CREATE TABLE #TeamMemberHistory
(
     syUserID INT
     , CRMTeamID INT
     , Active INT
     , HistoryStartDate DATETIME
     , HistoryEndDate DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO #TeamMemberHistory VALUES (17716, 637, 1, '2011-04-20 00:00:00.000', '2012-05-15 23:59:59.997')
INSERT INTO #TeamMemberHistory VALUES (17716, 634, 1, '2012-05-16 00:00:00.000', '2012-06-20 23:59:59.997')
INSERT INTO #TeamMemberHistory VALUES (17716, 628, 1, '2012-06-21 00:00:00.000', '2012-10-23 23:59:59.997')
INSERT INTO #TeamMemberHistory VALUES (17716, 636, 1, '2012-10-24 00:00:00.000', '2012-12-13 23:59:59.997')
INSERT INTO #TeamMemberHistory VALUES (17716, 628, 1, '2012-12-14 00:00:00.000', '2013-04-17 23:59:59.997')
INSERT INTO #TeamMemberHistory VALUES (17716, 676, 1, '2013-04-18 00:00:00.000', '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')



IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#TeamHistory', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TeamHistory
CREATE TABLE #TeamHistory
(
     CRMTeamID INT
     , TeamOwner_TeamID INT
     , Active INT
     , TeamName VARCHAR(25)
     , HistoryStartDate DATETIME
     , HistoryEndDate DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO #TeamHistory VALUES (628, 222, 1, 'Team 126', '2011-01-10 00:00:00.000', '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO #TeamHistory VALUES (634, 168, 1, 'Team 132', '2010-01-07 00:00:00.000', '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO #TeamHistory VALUES (636, 935, 1, 'Team 134', '2011-05-09 00:00:00.000', '2013-02-12 23:59:59.997')
INSERT INTO #TeamHistory VALUES (636, 935, 1, 'Team 134', '2013-02-13 00:00:00.000', '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO #TeamHistory VALUES (637, 192, 1, 'Team 135', '2010-08-03 00:00:00.000', '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO #TeamHistory VALUES (676, 242, 1, 'Team 360', '2011-05-21 00:00:00.000', '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')


SELECT * FROM #aoRepGroupMbrHistory ORDER BY Hist_EffectStart
SELECT * FROM #TeamMemberHistory ORDER BY HistoryStartDate
SELECT * FROM #TeamHistory ORDER BY CRMTeamID, HistoryStartDate


**RESULTS:**
syUserID     TeamName   CRMTeamID   TeamOwner_TeamId     aoRepGroupID   RepGroupName    dwEffectiveBeginDate    dwEffectiveEndDate
17716   Team 135    637  192    165 UG - All Skills Reps     01/01/2012 03/01/2012
17716   Team 135    637  192    772 UG - Tier 1 LC Reps  03/02/2012 05/15/2012
17716   Team 132     634    168 772  UG - Tier 1 LC Reps    05/16/2012  06/20/2012
17716    Team 126   628 222  772    UG - Tier 1 LC Reps 06/21/2012   06/26/2012
17716    Team 126   628 222  797    UG - Aggregators Reps   06/27/2012   10/23/2012
17716    Team 134   636 222  797    UG - Aggregators Reps   10/24/2012   11/08/2012
17716    Team 134   636 222  165    UG - All Skills Reps    11/09/2012   11/29/2012
17716   Team 134     636    222 797  UG - Aggregators Reps  11/30/2012  12/13/2012
17716    Team 126   628 222  797    UG - Aggregators Reps   12/14/2012   04/17/2013
17716   Team 360     676    424 797  UG - Aggregators Reps  04/18/2013  01/01/9999
```

Comment: It's hard work inferring your intent from example results.  Why not improve your question by adding an explanation?

Comment: the first row of your proposed result set has a "dwEffectiveBeginDate" of 2012-01-01, but none of your data has that date...  Where does that date come from?

Comment: Cool.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
DECLARE @aoRepGroupMbrHistory TABLE 
(
       syUserID INT
     , aoRepGroupID INT
     , Hist_EffectStart DATETIME
     , Hist_EffectiveEnd DATETIME
     , RepGroupName VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO @aoRepGroupMbrHistory 
VALUES 
      (17716, 165, '2010-06-03 00:00:00.000', '2012-03-01 23:59:59.997', 'UG - All Skills Reps')
    , (17716, 772, '2012-03-02 00:00:00.000', '2012-06-26 23:59:59.997', 'UG - Tier 1 LC Reps')
    , (17716, 797, '2012-06-27 00:00:00.000', '2012-11-08 23:59:59.997', 'UG - Aggregators Reps')
    , (17716, 165, '2012-11-09 00:00:00.000', '2012-11-29 23:59:59.997', 'UG - All Skills Reps')
    , (17716, 797, '2012-11-30 00:00:00.000', '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000', 'UG - Aggregators Reps')

DECLARE @TeamMemberHistory TABLE
(
       syUserID INT
     , CRMTeamID INT
     , Active INT
     , HistoryStartDate DATETIME
     , HistoryEndDate DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @TeamMemberHistory 
VALUES 
      (17716, 637, 1, '2011-04-20 00:00:00.000', '2012-05-15 23:59:59.997')
    , (17716, 634, 1, '2012-05-16 00:00:00.000', '2012-06-20 23:59:59.997')
    , (17716, 628, 1, '2012-06-21 00:00:00.000', '2012-10-23 23:59:59.997')
    , (17716, 636, 1, '2012-10-24 00:00:00.000', '2012-12-13 23:59:59.997')
    , (17716, 628, 1, '2012-12-14 00:00:00.000', '2013-04-17 23:59:59.997')
    , (17716, 676, 1, '2013-04-18 00:00:00.000', '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')

DECLARE @TeamHistory TABLE
(
       CRMTeamID INT
     , TeamOwner_TeamID INT
     , Active INT
     , TeamName VARCHAR(25)
     , HistoryStartDate DATETIME
     , HistoryEndDate DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @TeamHistory 
VALUES 
      (628, 222, 1, 'Team 126', '2011-01-10 00:00:00.000', '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')
    , (634, 168, 1, 'Team 132', '2010-01-07 00:00:00.000', '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')
    , (636, 935, 1, 'Team 134', '2011-05-09 00:00:00.000', '2013-02-12 23:59:59.997')
    , (636, 935, 1, 'Team 134', '2013-02-13 00:00:00.000', '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')
    , (637, 192, 1, 'Team 135', '2010-08-03 00:00:00.000', '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')
    , (676, 242, 1, 'Team 360', '2011-05-21 00:00:00.000', '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')

SELECT
      th.syUserID
    , t.TeamName
    , t.CRMTeamID
    , t.TeamOwner_TeamID
    , h.aoRepGroupID
    , h.RepGroupName
    , dwEffectiveBeginDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), th.HistoryStartDate, 101)
    , dwEffectiveEndDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), th.HistoryEndDate, 101) 
FROM @TeamHistory t
JOIN @TeamMemberHistory th ON t.CRMTeamID = th.CRMTeamID
JOIN @aoRepGroupMbrHistory h ON th.syUserID = h.syUserID
```